# Feynman path integral course online

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, path-integral

There are a lot of books dealing with Feynman path integrals. Are there any online courses introducing Feynman path integrals and their applications?

Comment: This question (v3) seems to have a [never-ending list](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=path+integral+lectures) of possible answers, cf. [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4561/2451) meta post.

Comment: Hi Nex_Friedrich, Res. recom. questions are restricted on Phys.SE because they tend to be _too broad_  _primarily opinion-based_ list questions. I'm closing this list question as a _duplicate,_ not because it is an exact duplicate, but to point in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

http://pirsa.org/C14034

I have gone through these lectures and enjoyed them.

The layout of the course is pretty much this:

- Construction of Q.M. Path Integral
- Euclidean Path Integral, Connection with S.M.
- Path Integral of a Scalar Field
- Feynman Rules resulting from the Path Integral treatment
- Generating Functionals / 1-loop Effective Actions
- Renormalization of Scalar Theory
- Grassmann Calculus & Fermionic Path Integrals
- Non Abelian Gauge Theory
- Gauge Fixing the Path Integral, Faddeev-Popov Determinant & Ghosts
- Renormalization of Non-Abelian Gauge Theory

Answer (score -3):

If you are looking for a full semester course online, the Urbana campus at the University of Illinois offers a good calc sequence online called [Netmath](https://netmath.illinois.edu/), and they cover working with and applications of path integrals.

Or are you looking for something shorter, or free, or cheaper:

There are some online textbooks/notes pages from [various](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LineIntegralsPtI.aspx) colleges as well as interactive graphing of line integrals. Others are non-interactive like e-textbooks, many free or free to subscribing universities. Possibly supplemented by something like Wolfram Alpha online to check answers and work on basic integrals.

Comment: Are we really talking about Feynman path integrals?

Comment: Note that line integrals are not *path integrals*!

Comment: Path (or Functional) integral and line integral aren't same thing. Like Newton's law of motion and string theory. Path integral is another way of doing QFT, QM.